# Thread Signal SIGABRT Exception

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm curious to know why I'm receiving an exception on this code and as to what this exception means. When I remove the `for` loop, as indicated below, it works fine. When I include it, I get an exception.

```
-(void) loadVenues {
    NSString *latLon = @"34.0500, -118.2500"; // approximate latLon of The Mothership (a.k.a Apple headquarters)
    NSString *clientID = kCLIENTID;
    NSString *clientSecret = kCLIENTSECRET;
    //34.0500° N, 118.2500
    NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"ll" : latLon,
                                  @"client_id" : clientID,
                                  @"client_secret" : clientSecret,
                                  @"categoryId" : @"4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735",
                                  @"v" : @"20140118"};
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/v2/venues/search"
                                           parameters:queryParams
                                              success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            _venues = mappingResult.array;
            NSMutableArray *temp = [(NSArray*)_venues mutableCopy];                                   
            for (int i =0; i < _venues.count; i++)                                            
            {
                NSUInteger index = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j <_venues.count; j++)
                {
                    //((MyObjectType *) [myArray objectAtIndex:0]).intProperty = 12345;
                    if(((Venue *) [temp objectAtIndex:index]).location.distance > 0)
                    {
                        Venue *holder= [temp objectAtIndex:index];
                        [temp removeObjectAtIndex:index];
                        NSUInteger indexer = index +1;
                        [temp addObject:[temp objectAtIndex:indexer]];
                        //replace a with a+1
                        [temp replaceObjectAtIndex:indexer withObject:holder];

                        //[temp addObject:holder atIndex: index+1];
                        //a[i+1]=holder;
                        index++;
                    }
                    else {index++;}
                }
            }
            _venues = temp;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"What do you mean by 'there is no coffee?': %@", error);
        }
    ];
}
```

I'm getting an exception at this line:

```
[temp addObject:[temp objectAtIndex:indexer]];
```

And I'm not sure why.

Here is the error:

```
  2014-07-02 21:43:12.536 CoffeeKit[63581:60b] I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit logging initialized...
2014-07-02 21:43:12.655 CoffeeKit[63581:60b] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:150 GET 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735&client_id=ZE5VJOPEO1PP3NDFVCM3O2ZUXWDDJRB20XDDGH3OETBKOVZB&client_secret=5LGY2CEASBQZQS5P0LYFICWDKMDOHJJ00F3G24LT4J4DX4X3&ll=34.0500%2C%20-118.2500&v=20140118'
2014-07-02 21:43:13.085 CoffeeKit[63581:f03] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:220 GET 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&ll=34.0500%2C%20-118.2500&v=20140118' (200 OK / 30 objects) [request=0.4171s mapping=0.0128s total=0.4486s]
2014-07-02 21:43:13.087 CoffeeKit[63581:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 29 beyond bounds [0 .. 28]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023a0495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001020ff99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102346745 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 213
    3   CoffeeKit                           0x0000000100002efa __34-[MasterViewController loadVenues]_block_invoke + 602
    4   CoffeeKit                           0x000000010009310b __66-[RKObjectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke244 + 91
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102c9a851 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102cad72d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102c9d3fc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 354
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023fe289 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010234b854 __CFRunLoopRun + 1764
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010234ad83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001033e2f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000100cace33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    13  CoffeeKit                           0x0000000100003733 main + 115
    14  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102efe5fd start + 1
    15  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Xcode > Breakpoints > Add Exception Breakpoint, then rerun.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: The breakpoint is at the beginning of the second for loop. @Charlie

Comment: What does your actual log say?

Comment: @Charlie 2014-07-02 21:19:04.532 CoffeeKit[62728:60b] I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit logging initialized...
2014-07-02 21:19:04.666 CoffeeKit[62728:60b] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:150 GET 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735&client_id=ZE5VJOPEO1PP3NDFVCM3O2ZUXWDDJRB20XDDGH3OETBKOVZB&client_secret=5LGY2CEASBQZQS5P0LYFICWDKMDOHJJ00F3G24LT4J4DX4X3&ll=34.0500%2C%20-118.2500&v=20140118'
2014-07-02 21:19:05.031

Comment: CoffeeKit[62728:3107] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:220 GET 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735&client_id=ZE5VJOPEO1PP3NDFVCM3O2ZUXWDDJRB20XDDGH3OETBKOVZB&client_secret=5LGY2CEASBQZQS5P0LYFICWDKMDOHJJ00F3G24LT4J4DX4X3&ll=34.0500%2C%20-118.2500&v=20140118' (200 OK / 30 objects) [request=0.3509s mapping=0.0132s total=0.3833s]
(lldb)

Comment: Update your post with your error log. Saying you got a SIGABRT is essentially telling me something's wrong somewhere and nothing else.

Comment: @Charlie updated it, after messing around with the code a little, I fixed the first exception, but I'm struggling on this exception up there ^.

Comment: What does the actual crash log look like though? You posted what happens before the crash occurs, but not the stack trace afterwards.

Comment: @Charlie how do I access the crash log? Is it not just the output under the 'All Output' tab?

Comment: Yes but I'm guessing you're stopping the execution of your app as soon as `(lldb)` appears in your console. Disable your breakpoints and run again.

Comment: @Charlie oh ok, I deactivated breakpoints and put the output back in

Comment: What are you doing posting your CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET in the question. Redact it.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer Unfortunately the keys are remained in editing history. I wish OP to ask the site administrators to erase the (maybe?) sensitive informations in editing history ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your stack, your error is occurring because you attempt to access the object at index 29, which is outside of the array's bounds:

> *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 29 beyond bounds [0 .. 28]

In your case, it's probably arising from this line:

```
NSUInteger indexer = index +1;
[temp addObject:[temp objectAtIndex:indexer]];
```

Which I'm assuming you're using to get the value of the next object. Once the array reaches the 28th object, however, you attempt to access the imaginary 29th object.

Bottom line: refactor your code so that you only access objects that exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting out of bounds by accessing the NEXT element in the array, 2 things. you can directly use 'j' to access the element (instead of index, so u dont have to increment it urself) and you can change your for from

```
for (int j = 0; j <_venues.count; j++)
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j <_venues.count-1; j++)
```

By the way if all you need is sorting, NSMutableArray offers many options:

```
Rearranging Content
– exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:
– sortUsingDescriptors:
– sortUsingComparator:
– sortWithOptions:usingComparator:
– sortUsingFunction:context:
– sortUsingSelector:
```